# assigning undefined to JSON property value

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I am unable to extract the JSON property value from the JSON returned from my server running in a wordpress environment.

Client Universal Woody Snippet Script

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>JSON string output from a JavaScript object.</h2>

<h4>JSON String Value is:</h4><p id="demo"> </p>
<h4>JSON Symbol2 Value is:</h4><p id="json_symbol2"> </p>
<h4>JSON Symbol Value is:</h4><p id="json_symbol"> </p>
<h4>JSON Price Value is:</h4><p id="json_price"> </p>

<script>    
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open("GET", "https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_holdings2.php"); 
ourRequest.onload = function() {
var obj =   ourRequest.responseText;
var myJSON =    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
//var myJSONprice =     JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.price));
console.log( myJSON );

console.log( myJSON.symbol );
console.log(myJSON.price);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
//document.getElementById("json_symbol2").innerHTML = myJSONprice;
document.getElementById("json_symbol").innerHTML = myJSON.symbol;
document.getElementById("json_price").innerHTML = myJSON.price;
}
ourRequest.send();  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server PHP Script

```
<?php

/*
 * ajax_stock_holdings2.php
 */
$filename = 'ajax_stock_holdings2.php';

 /* Loads the WordPress environment and template */
require( '../../wp-blog-header.php' );

global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();

// DataTables PHP library
include( "../lib/DataTables.php" );


//$stock_id = $_GET['stock_id']; // manually setting variable for testing
$stock_id = 1293;
$stock_array = array();

// check if variable is NOT blank pass JSON back to client 
if ($stock_id  <> "") {

//echo "the value of stock_id is :" . $stock_id . ":" . "\n";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO(strtolower($sql_details['type']) . ":host=" . $sql_details['host'] . ";dbname=" . $sql_details['db'], $sql_details['user'], $sql_details['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//    echo $filename . "Connected successfully" . "\n\n";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
//    echo $filename . "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT id, symbol, name, price FROM dm_stocks WHERE id = $stock_id");
        foreach ($result as $row) {

        array_push( $stock_array, array('symbol'=>$row['symbol'], 'price'=>$row['price'] ) );
        }

echo json_encode($stock_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
}

?>
```

JSON returned

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "GSK.LSE",
        "price": 1744
    }
]
```

Output from client script

```
Test JSON
JSON string output from a JavaScript object.
JSON String Value is:
[ { "symbol": "GSK.LSE", "price": 1744 } ]

JSON Symbol2 Value is:
JSON Symbol Value is:
undefined

JSON Price Value is:
undefined
```

I have tried uncommenting the commented lines for Symbol2 which results in an error i.e. assigning the property value before stringify

```
VM23451:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload ((index):303)
```

line 303 is

```
var myJSONprice =   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.price));
```

Any help on this issue is much appreciated, many thanks Colin

I am trying to integrate the above code to write the price as message on the datatables.net editor modal, the client snippet extract is below

```
    editor.dependent( 'dm_transactions.stock_id', function ( val, data, callback ) {
    $.ajax( {
        url: '../../Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_transactions.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        // pass stock_id value to server php script
        data: { "stock_id": val },
        success: function (json) {          
            callback(json);

ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open("GET", "https://dividendlook.co.uk/Editor-PHP-1.9.0/controllers/ajax_stock_transactions.php");  
ourRequest.onload = function() {
obj =   ourRequest.responseText;    
myJSONobj =     JSON.parse(obj);
myJSONstr =    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log( myJSONobj );
console.log( myJSONstr );

console.log(myJSONobj[0].symbol);
console.log(myJSONobj[0].price);

document.getElementById("json_obj").innerHTML = myJSONobj;
document.getElementById("json_str").innerHTML = myJSONstr;
document.getElementById("json_symbol").innerHTML = myJSONobj[0].symbol;
document.getElementById("json_price").innerHTML = myJSONobj[0].price;
}
ourRequest.send();  

editor.field("dm_transactions.price").set(myJSONobj[0].price);
    }),{
        event: 'keyup change'
    };

    editor.dependent('dm_transactions.stock_id', function ( val, data, callback ){
        return { messages: { 'dm_transactions.price': 'Yesterday Close : ' + myJSONobj[0].price }};

    },{
    event: 'keyup change'
    });
```

The error generated is below

```
(index):570 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at (index):570
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (dataTables.editor.js:2602)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.js:8249)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:8327)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:354)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.js:189)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.js:8326)
    at dataTables.editor.js:9159
```

line (index):570 is below

```
editor.field("dm_transactions.price").set(myJSONobj[0].price);
```

Any help in how I integrate this code into my datatables code shown above, would be appreciated thanks Colin

Comment: Your PHP script returns an array (`array_push`, `[ { ... } ]`). Treat it accordingly.

Comment: Get rid of the JSON.stringify(object) as the response is already a string

`var myJSON =    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`
Should be 
`var myJSON =    JSON.parse(obj);`

Now you stringify something thats already a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from your PHP code is an array of associative arrays, which once `json_encoded` becomes an array of objects. So to access the individual values you need to iterate over the array, or, if there will only be one row returned from the query, you can simply use the `[0]` element e.g.

```
console.log(myJSON[0].symbol);
console.log(myJSON[0].price);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I appreciated that the JSON was an array, my mistake, the combination of changing MyJSON = JSON.parse(obj) and myJSON[0].price etc has solved the problem. Many Thanks Colin

Comment: I have added some additions to the call showing my attempt to integrate the code into my datatables.net code, details shown above, any help on thsi would be appreciated thanks Colin

Comment: Should I raise another call for this question ? Colin

Comment: @colin sorry about the slow response - been sleeping. It looks like you are trying to set `editor.field("dm_transactions.price").set(myJSONobj[0].price);` outside the callback from sending `ourRequest`, so `myJSONobj` won't be set at that point.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply, sorry for my delay, I have tried using global variables setting value within callback and setting the editor field value to the variable to no avail, so I may need to go back to datatables.net for a solution. Thanks Colin

Comment: @colin yeah - if trying to set the value inside the callback didn't work, then it's probably time for a  new question. Sorry I couldn't be of more help...

Comment: Hi Nick, I appreciate your help, I have moved issue forward. Thanks Colin